# Can't connect legacy Spring web app to Okta

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, openid, okta

For a few days now, I'm desperately trying to migrate the authentication system of a legacy web app from CAS to Okta.

versions: Spring (no Boot) 4.3.30.RELEASE + Spring Security 4.2.20.RELEASE

Included dependencies are (versions omitted - see above):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-openid</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Here's how my Spring Security class looks like:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class MyAppWebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/public/**")
                .antMatchers("/resources/**")
                .antMatchers("/javax.faces.resource/**")
        ;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                /**
                 * Some URIs need to be authenticated
                 */
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**").authenticated()
                .antMatchers("/protected/**").authenticated()

                /**
                 * Some not... (these "APIs" are public)
                 */
                .antMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()

                .and()

                .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/public/logout.xhtml")

                .and()

                /**
                 * CSRF needs to be disabled.
                 */
                .csrf().disable()

                /**
                 * Authentication w/ OpenID.
                 */
                .openidLogin();
    }

}
```

The app starts fine in Tomcat (it is a "web" app packaged as a .war) and when I try to access to the app via http://localhost:8080/myapp it redirects to /myapp/login then displays a "simple" login page with an "Identity" text field (Side note: I would prefer it displays the Okta login page... but couldn't find how to do that).

I found via the Okta docs that URL https://dev--mycompany.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default/.well-known/openid-configuration returns this JSON:

```json
{"issuer":"https://dev--mycompany.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default","authorization_endpoint":"https://dev--mycompany.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default/v1/authorize","token_endpoint":"https://dev--mycompany.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default/v1/token","userinfo_endpoint":"https://dev--mycompany.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default/v1/userinfo","registration_endpoint":"https://dev--mycompany.oktapreview.com/oauth2/v1/clients","jwks_uri":"https://dev--mycompany.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default/v1/keys","response_types_supported":["code","id_token","code id_token","code token","id_token token","code id_token token"],"response_modes_supported":["query","fragment","form_post","okta_post_message"],"grant_types_supported":["authorization_code","implicit","refresh_token","password"],"subject_types_supported":["public"],"id_token_signing_alg_values_supported":["RS256"],"scopes_supported":["openid","profile","email","address","phone","offline_access"],"token_endpoint_auth_methods_supported":["client_secret_basic","client_secret_post","client_secret_jwt","private_key_jwt","none"],"claims_supported":["iss","ver","sub","aud","iat","exp","jti","auth_time","amr","idp","nonce","name","nickname","preferred_username","given_name","middle_name","family_name","email","email_verified","profile","zoneinfo","locale","address","phone_number","picture","website","gender","birthdate","updated_at","at_hash","c_hash"],"code_challenge_methods_supported":["S256"],"introspection_endpoint":"https://dev--mycompany.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default/v1/introspect","introspection_endpoint_auth_methods_supported":["client_secret_basic","client_secret_post","client_secret_jwt","private_key_jwt","none"],"revocation_endpoint":"https://dev--mycompany.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default/v1/revoke","revocation_endpoint_auth_methods_supported":["client_secret_basic","client_secret_post","client_secret_jwt","private_key_jwt","none"],"end_session_endpoint":"https://dev--mycompany.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default/v1/logout","request_parameter_supported":true,"request_object_signing_alg_values_supported":["HS256","HS384","HS512","RS256","RS384","RS512","ES256","ES384","ES512"]}
```

Hoped it would help the system properly set up... alas, when I enter the above URL in the Identity field, these logs show up:

```
[booster]-[http-nio-8080-exec-5]-[10:53:01.232]-[]-[INFO ]-[org.openid4java.discovery.Discovery] Starting discovery on URL identifier: https://dev--mycompany.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default/.well-known/openid-configuration
[booster]-[http-nio-8080-exec-5]-[10:53:01.945]-[]-[INFO ]-[org.openid4java.discovery.yadis.YadisResolver] Yadis discovered 0 endpoints from: https://dev--mycompany.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default/.well-known/openid-configuration
[booster]-[http-nio-8080-exec-5]-[10:53:01.945]-[]-[INFO ]-[org.openid4java.discovery.Discovery] No OpenID service endpoints discovered through Yadis; attempting HTML discovery...
[booster]-[http-nio-8080-exec-5]-[10:53:02.129]-[]-[INFO ]-[org.openid4java.discovery.html.HtmlResolver] HTML discovery completed on: https://dev--mycompany.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default/.well-known/openid-configuration
[booster]-[http-nio-8080-exec-5]-[10:53:02.129]-[]-[INFO ]-[org.openid4java.discovery.Discovery] Discovered 0 OpenID endpoints.
[booster]-[http-nio-8080-exec-5]-[10:53:02.129]-[]-[ERROR]-[org.openid4java.consumer.ConsumerManager] Association attempt, but no discovey endpoints provided.
```

... and the HTML "login" page returns to URI /login?error with this error message:

```
Your login attempt was not successful, try again.

Reason: Unable to process claimed identity 'https://dev--mycompany.oktapreview.com/oauth2/default/'

Login with OpenID Identity
Identity: < >
```

I'm totally lost.

For now every single page I found - be it official Spring or Okta docs, various tutorials or blog posts - either expects Spring Boot (not my case here), or Spring Security 5.0 (not the case either).

So I absolutely don't know what to do; what is missing in this config to make it work?

PS: the app already include an implementation of `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService` which returns user details fetched from a local database, but that's it.

Comment: I wouldn't use spring-security-openid or the other dependencies you have. I'd recommend using the Okta Spring Boot starter instead. https://github.com/okta/okta-spring-boot

Comment: If you want to get something up and running quickly, install the [Okta CLI](https://cli.okta.com) and run `okta start spring-boot`. Here's a video that shows how it works. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dURkaz0kBSU

Comment: @MattRaible I think you misread the first few lines... I can NOT use Spring Boot; this is a legacy app which can't be upgraded.

Comment: I wrote a post back in 2018 that shows how to use Spring Security 5 to secure a non-Spring Boot app. I'm not sure if it will work with Spring Security 4, but it might. https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/09/12/secure-java-ee-rest-api#secure-your-java-rest-api-with-spring-security

Comment: Read that blog post earlier while searching, and - minus the few hiccups like twice the `clientRegistrationRepository()` method or the last line `ClientRegistrations.fromOidcIssuerLocation(…)` alone in the class body - it doesn’t work *as is* because `.oauth2Login()` doesn’t exist on `HttpSecurity` class + several classes are new to Spring Security 5.x and I’ve not found *yet* the equivalent in Spring Security 4.x - so I'm stuck for now...